# Trying to Get Information from an XLSX Spreadsheet in an XLA File

Tags: excel, vba

I have an XLA file with 9 Modules, each containing a macro, with data in sheets in the XLA file.  I've used this successfully for 18 years, but have run out of room in the XLA file to store more data.  I've tried moving the data into an XLSX file and linking to it from the XLA file, but I keep getting "Type Mismatch" errors which I think are coming from my Workbooks.Open statement.  I don't see why; it seems right from every other example I've seen.  I need to keep the XLA file since there are tens of thousands of other Excel files that link to it.  Any thoughts on how to fix this would be appreciated.

```
Function Mortality(TableNum As Integer, Optional SetChange As Integer, _
 Optional TableLoad As Double, Optional ScaleNum As Integer, _
 Optional ScaleSetChange As Integer, Optional ScaleLoad As Double, _
 Optional StartYear As Integer, Optional EndYear As Integer, _
 Optional YOB As Integer, Optional CurrentYear As Integer) As Variant
'
' Dimension Variables
'
Dim NumberofTables As Integer, I As Integer, NumberofScales As Integer, ProjMax As Integer
Dim ProjStart As Integer
Dim StartPoint As Range, StartScalePoint As Range
Dim MortTable As Variant, ScaleTable As Variant
Dim ScaleTable2D As Variant
Dim Start2D As Integer, End2D As Integer, J As Integer
Dim ScaleBook As String, ScaleColumns As Integer, Scale1stCol As Integer
Dim StartLoop As Integer, EndLoop As Integer
Dim ActuarialDataFile As Workbook
Set ActuarialDataFile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Z:\Computer Related\Installation Files\Annuity Factor Program\Annuity.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
'
' Set Basic Mortality Table before revision
'
Set StartPoint = ActuarialDataFile.Worksheets("Mortality Tables").Range("A1")
```

Comment: If the posted function is being called from a cell as a UDF then it can't open any files...  You could try instead using ADO to query data from the other Excel file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It took me a while to get the ADO working since I have not used that before. Unfortunately, an ADO recordset is limited 255 columns, so it had the same issue as the XLA file. The ultimate solution was to transpose the data and rewrite the VBA code accordingly, which leaves plenty of room (extra rows) to add more data. Ultimately, I may move the data to another Excel sheet or Access to reduce the size of the XLA add-in, and use the ADO approach to query it.